# How to Use Table View Cell Outside Table View Function

Tags: swift

i need to change my image in cell using view will appear. But i can't use my cell in view will appear here what i've done

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    let cell: HomeCellTableViewCell = self.tableCity.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! HomeCellTableViewCell
    if session == nil {
        print("first")
        cell.iconForDownload.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_download"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        print("second")
        cell.iconForDownload.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_next_green"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

it print "first" but the image still didn't change

in my `cellForRowAt` :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: HomeCellTableViewCell = self.tableCity.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! HomeCellTableViewCell

    let city = listData[indexPath.row]
    cell.labelNameCity.text = city.region
    cell.labelNameCityJpn.text = city.regionJpn

    let stringImage = config.BASE_URL+city.imgArea
    let url = URL(string: stringImage.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))
    urlDownload = config.BASE_URL+kota.urlDownload
    urlDownloadFinal = URL(string: urlDownload.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))
    if session == nil {
        cell.imageCity.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.iconForDownload.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_download"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        cell.imageCity.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.iconForDownload.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_next_green"), for: .normal)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: consider reloading table with `reloadData()`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `cellForRow(at:)` to get the `cell` it will return optional `UITableViewCell` so use `if let` or `guard let` to wrapped the optional.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) //Set your row and section
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? HomeCellTableViewCell {
        //access cell
    }
}
```

**Note:** The batter approach is to set your datasource array and simply reload the affected table rows using `reloadRows(at:with:)`.

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0) //Set your row and section
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Comment: i get error `Value of UITableViewCell has no member iconForDownload`

Comment: i'm sure, i just want to change the image after the view appear again. First if cell tapped it download file and after download completed it open and push to another view controller, if back button tapped, the image in cell changed

Comment: @ArielGemilang If you want to change image when you come back from secondview the batter approach is to use delegate because `viewWillAppear` call 2 time in your case first when you load this screen first time second you press back button and come to this controller.